# Benyamin born in Padan-Aram?

Tags: vayishlach

In [Genesis 35](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0135.htm) the birth narrative of Benyamin is told where Rachel is traveling on the road from Bethel to Bethlehem (Ephrath) in central Judea.

Later in verse 26 it says that all of Jacob's sons were born in the field of Aram which is present day Syria (Padan-Aram).

How exactly could Benyamin have been born in Padan-Aram if we were just told that he was born in central Judea?

Comment: Hi Shig and welcome to Mi Yodeia! Hope to see you around a bit. :)

Answer (score 5):

Ibn Ezra asks this question and answers that the verse is going by the majority of the children.

Chizkuni says that Rachel prayed in Padan-Aram to have another son, a prayer which was answered with the birth of Binyamin, so it is as if he were born there.